# why cmd.exe install pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

I ran `pip install --up` and got the following:

```
C:\Users\evaim>pip install -r requirements.txt
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

C:\Users\evaim>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/db/9e38760b32e3e7f40cce46dd5fb107b8c73840df38f0046d8e6514e675a1/pip-19.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 2.9MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 19.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-19.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-19.0.3
Successfully installed pip-19.2.3

C:\Users\evaim>pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Comment: do you have file `'requirements.txt'` in folder `C:\Users\evaim` ?

Comment: I think you are probably just in the wrong directory.  (Check the instructions you are following.  Did you miss a "cd" command?)

Comment: No i did miss a "cd' command.

Answer (score 0):

By running `pip install -r requirements.txt` you instruct pip to install packages listed in a file with the path `requirements.txt`. Make sure to have a file called `requirements.txt` in your folder of execution (`C:\Users\evaim`) following the [Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format).